# Codeigniter Search User and details

Tags: database, codeigniter, search

DB Table:  `tblcg`

`id | firstName | lastName | zipcode | City`

When user enter zipcode(like- **42872**) in the search form and click search button then show like this.......

```
----------------------------------------------
|     Name      |   Zipcode   |     City     | 
----------------------------------------------
|  Devid Johne  |    42872    |  Northbrook  |
----------------------------------------------
|  Betty Flore  |    42872    |  Northbrook  |
----------------------------------------------
|  Abard Gree   |    42872    |  Northbrook  |
----------------------------------------------
```

**NB:** The result show should be on the same page.

**Please Help me do this. I know you can do it. Please sir do it**

Comment: you can use ajax for  the result on same page

Comment: I don't need another result. I need the results that I will search.

Comment: If you can, please enter the code

Comment: Have you write any code . I can correct your code

Comment: Where is your code? Your question is likely to be closed unless you edit it to something more specific, including the code you have tried. SO is not a code-writing service. Have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is you can do it.**

**View :**

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('search/search_keyword');?>" method = "post">
<input type="text" name = "keyword" />
<input type="submit" value = "Search" />
</form>
```

**Controller :**

```
Class Search Extends CI_Contrller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('mymodel');
    }

    function search_keyword()
    {
        $keyword    =   $this->input->post('keyword');
        $data['results']    =   $this->mymodel->search($keyword);
        $this->load->view('result_view',$data);
    }

}
```

**Model :**

```
Class Mymodel Extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function search($keyword)
    {
        $this->db->like('zipcode ',$keyword);
        $query  =   $this->db->get('tblcg');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

**EDITS :**

Here is the view to display data. `result_view.php`

```
<table>
<?php foreach($results as $row){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->name?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->zipcode ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->City?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: I am always ready for a needed people through this kind of website.

Comment: Sir i need your help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60370606/search-multiple-table-data-in-codeigniter